# How to restart the application again if system is restart

Tags: java, winforms, system

I am working in a java application and if the system is turnoff then the application will not be close properly and if we again login they show the message already login but the icon is deleted that menu list i have to code for logout I want to restart the application can any one help me 
i want only two thing 
1. if the system is shutdown my application will automatically logout 
other wise if i start again the system it will show its icon in task bar

Comment: winforms is for c#. What gui framework are you using?

Comment: I am using swing in java and its a desktop application

Comment: I am using swing in java and its a desktop application

Answer (score 0):

You could try [ShutdownHooks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/lang/hook-design.html). This will only work though if the JVM is quitted gracefully. If you want to provide a maximum of certainty that the program will quit correctly, you'll have to rely on a library for POSIX-events. There is no library for POSIX-events in the standard-API though and it's a quite easy to mess things up really bad, so ShutdownHooks is definitly the preferred solution. You can register a ShutdownHook this way:

```
Runable hook = () -> {
     System.out.println("Quitting at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
}
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(hook));
```

This will print the current time (as long) when the JVM is closing.

Comment: If i used that SHutdownHooks it will logout my application. because my application is connected to the server. and at the time of log out it will send the logout time to the local database and then again login time it will fetch time time of that close time so if i used that it will do that same task

Comment: Is this a question? If so please clarify

Comment: @RaviJat what the ShutdownHook itself does depends on how you write it. You can simply register any `Runable` via `System.addShutdownHook` to run when the JVM shuts down

Comment: i jest want to close the database connection and logout the application if system(window is shutdown) i use that create a class that have shutdowmhook run method and call it in the main class of the application but it not work i dont know how to use it can you help me yo defind where i used that method

Comment: I've added an example for how to use ShutdownHooks

Comment: thanks and can you tell me that it  work after system shutdown and my application is is logout perfactaly

Comment: i personally haven't worked that much with shutdownhooks, but according to the docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) this will work for your problem

Comment: ok show can you send me that code and also mention where i am call that class of shutdownhook class in the frame class of application or the coding main functionality class.

Comment: @RaviJat in that case it would probably make the most sense to register the shutdownhook right after the login. Though in general you can register the hook anywhere. Basically you'll just have to make sure that the hook is registered at the time the application might close

Comment: but how i am fond the close time of application if the system is shutdown into running stat of the application

Comment: The thread/the runable that runs in the thread will be started when the application is closing. You can retrieve the time with `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: ok I will try that code. Paul can I make my logout code into a thread and add that thread into the hook so it will work or not the logout code is into the code and can i also use that thread in manual like previous one i use that code into that class where i call  for the  logout and call that hook also into this class it work

Comment: @RaviJat sry, but i don't have the slightest clue what this question is about.

Comment: in my application the code that I use for logout. In click of the logout button

Comment: I use that code into hook thread .if i do that so can i use that thread into my logout button click and also use that thread into the shutdownhook thread It is possible that i use both place the same thread and i defined that shutdownhook thread into that particular place and call that into there that class into the end of my application and not start into the begin of my class its work or not

Comment: Threads arent reusable. And using the same runable can be dangerous if the runable has variables. So id use two instances of the same runable instead

Comment: paul this is work but if my system is forcefully shutdown its not work and also one more thing is that into this file modification operation is work but the logout is not work and the entry of the database is not perform if you give me your email id so i send you that cade that i use and also tell what is the problem into that

Comment: Id prefer a github repository over mailing. For forcefully shuting down: this shouldn't happen in the first place and can only be handled by a library for processing posix events

Comment: but in shutdown time it not have that much time to logout the application and one more thing is that when i log out it store current time into the database that comes from the server i think the internet connection is close so they don't fetch the current time and not update into the database that way i am ask your email so i diffing in brief what hepand into it